# Calculus rule $d(f+g)=df + dg$ and combined functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, physics, mathematical-physics

Suppose that we have two functions, namely $f$ and $g$ that are both functions of one variable, call it $x$. We can combine the two and get a new function $h$ of one variable again in the following way:

$$h(x)=(f\cdot g)(x)$$

What if we had name the variable of the second function as "$y$". Could we then combine them in the same way as they were both funtion of "$x$"? I would say yes because in either case the mapping is from $\rm{R}$ to $\rm{R}$. But what troubles me is if "$x$" and "$y$" were both physical quantities then the new quantity would be a function of two physical quantities (variables). Another thing that troubles me is that we can write for a function of two variables:

$$h(x,y)=f(x)\cdot g(y)$$

How can we write it in this case but not in the first case? Does the "$y$" serves only as a convention to understand that our function is of two variables and not one, i.e. the mapping is from $\rm{R}^2$ to $\rm{R}$? Lets suppose that $f(x)=2x$ and $g(y)=2y$. In the first case if I combine them I would get the function of one variable:

$$h(x)=4x^2$$

whereas in the second case I would get the function of two variables:

$$h(x,y)=4xy$$

What determines if the combined function would be of one or two variables?

**Combination of functions with different variables**

Lets suppose now that again $f(x)=2x$ but $g$ is function of three variables $g(x,y,z)=2xy+z$. Can I get a combined function by adding them, such that:

$$h(x,y,z)=(f+g)(x,y,z)=2xy+ z + 2x$$

What is the proper way to combine functions? Should they have the same number of variables? What if the variables are physical quantities? I started to think about this when I say a common calculus rule that states:

$$d(f+g)= df + dg$$

I thought that in order to be able to perform such an operation both functions must have the same variables. But in Thermodynamics one can perform such an operation even when $f$ and $g$ have different variables. For example we define, Gibbs free energy $G=H-TS$ where $H=H(S,P,n)$ and $S=S(U,V,n)$. We can take the differential of this function:

$$dG=dH-TdS-SdT$$

without actually care about the number of variables that $H$, $T$ and $S$ have.

Comment: When we talk about combining functions such as $(f\cdot g)$ we require that $f$ and $g$ both have the same domain and codomain and $\cdot$ is a defined operation in the codomain.  Sure... you could have written $g(y)=2y$ instead of $g(x)=2x$ but these both describe the same function.  The result of $(f\cdot g)$ is another function with the same domain... in your example at the top, the domain $\Bbb R$, meaning that the result is still a function of a single variable.

Comment: Ok, so combination requires that both have the same domain and codomain. But why when say that a function can be seperated $h(x,y)$ as $f(x) \cdot g(y)$ we name the variables. Both $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ map from $\rm{R}$ to $\rm{R}$.

Comment: We can talk about the function $(f\cdot g)$ which is the result of an operation on $f,g$ where we would consider $(f\cdot g)(x)$ which simplifies by definition to $f(x)\cdot g(x)$ where both inputs must be the same.  Do not confuse that with $f(x)\cdot g(y)$ where the inputs could be different.  That is not the result of an operation on the functions $f,g$ themselves but is rather the result of an operation on the *outputs* of the functions applied to two possibly different inputs.  We could absolutely have $h(x,y)=f(x)\cdot g(y)$ in some cases and that is perfectly valid.

Comment: Why name the variables when separating $h(x,y)$ (*if we even could*) to $f(x)\cdot g(y)$?  So that we can keep track of which input was which.  $h$ was in your example taking two separate arguments... the first argument of which we routinely choose to call $x$ and the second argument of which we routinely choose to call $y$.  There is no real significance to naming them these specifically, but it allow us to then unambiguously refer back to them and know which was which.  The first input happens to be what $f$ acts on and the second what $g$ acts on in the example.

Comment: Does the same applies for the differential rule? I mean should both $f$ and $g$ be functions of the same variables?

Comment: @Anton the derivative is defined with respect to a variable. If a function has more then one variable then you talk about partial derivatives, one for each variable, and directional derivatives which are a linear combination of the partial derivatives. In any case yes, the differential rule that you stated in the title is always true given that all the terms are defined and make sense.